# Is is possible to set a default value to a model without any javascript

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use radio buttons that shows different elements with ng-show, and i dont get it to set a default value in the model.

I've got the following example code [(also fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ysxR9/1/).

```
<div ng-app> 
    <input type="radio" ng-model="input" name="input" value="a" />
    <input type="radio" ng-model="input" name="input" value="b" />
    <h2 ng-show="input == 'a'">A</h2>
    <h2 ng-show="input == 'b'">B</h2>
</div>
```

I've tried with `checked="checked"` but it gets overdid by angular. `ng-checked="true"` gives that radiobutton propper check, but it doesnt set the model to 'a'.

I know it's possible to fix this in a controller but i want to do it completely without any javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-init` http://jsfiddle.net/ysxR9/2/

```
<div ng-app ng-init="input='a'">

    <input type="radio" ng-model="input" name="input" value="a" /> A <br />
    <input type="radio" ng-model="input" name="input" value="b" /> B <br />

    <br />
    <br />

    <h2 ng-show="input == 'a'">A</h2>
    <h2 ng-show="input == 'b'">B</h2>

</div>
```

Usually its usage is [not quite recommended](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide) but in single cases it is fine to use it.

What `ng-init` does is to execute the given expression in the context of the current scope, i.e. `$scope.$eval(expression);` this means that you can put the directive wherever you want, just be aware of the target scope:

```
<div ng-app>

    <input type="radio" ng-model="input" name="input" value="a" ng-init="input='a'" /> A <br />
    <input type="radio" ng-model="input" name="input" value="b" /> B <br />

    <br />
    <br />

    <h2 ng-show="input == 'a'">A</h2>
    <h2 ng-show="input == 'b'">B</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, however it would be even better if i could just add something to the input element, instead of the parent. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, i can just apply this to the element, Thanks!

Comment: You can add the `ng-init` directive to the input element, it is not required to add it to the root. I'll complement my answer in a minute.

Comment: in your example first input === second input because ng-model -> input, in scope is't $scope.input, what == 'a'

Comment: @KoIIIeY, well...as far as I understand you suggest use of `===` instead of `==`. Yeah, usually it is better practice but in the current case it doesn't matter. Unfortunately I wasn't able to understand your second suggestion.

Comment: all your inputs links on variable $scope.input. When you change first input it change $scope.input variable, that change your second input because ng-model of first and of second input is "input". 
ng-model creates two-direction binding to the scope variable.
I just try to say that you can erase your second input :D